# Display entries related to Category Field

Tags: templating, categories

I'm sorry If this has been answered before, but I couldn't find any answer that would work for me. Maybe I'm just treating category fields the wrong way and I should be trying to do this with tags.

Basically, I created a category group called **colors**. I also have several categories like **green**, **blue**, **red**...
I assigned URLs that look like `mysite/colors/red`, `mysite/colors/blue`.

All of the colors point to the same template `colors/index.html`

How can I display only the entries in `craft.entries.section('news')` that are in the "red" color category when I visit `mysite/colors/red`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `relatedTo` filter. See the docs here: https://craftcms.com/support/entries-related-to-category where `category` is your last URL segment (eg red).

Just a quick addition... if your category URL for the category group matches what you've used above `mysite/colors/red` and you are using the category template for that group then you will have a `category` variable already to use in the `relatedTo` filter.

Comment: That worked. I guess I was overthinking it. Thanks Mike